# Document Root; Login Variables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I recently posted a question here; however, in the great answers that I got, I was told that my connection queries were unsafe and deprecated.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "userX", "passX") or die('Could not connect to server');
    mysql_select_db("dbX", $con) or die('Could not connect to database');      
    $query="SELECT fieldX,filedX2 FROM tableX WHERE varX";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

Apparently, the material from which I learned is old. So I looked into this issue and came across these two items:

1.*"In real practice, it would be best to place username and password in a folder out of the Apache Web server's path so it's not accessible via the Web."*

2.*"Put username and password in a file that is not in the document root of the web application"*

```
<?php

include("connection.php");

$link = mysql_connect($connection_server, $connection_user,$connection_password);
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);

?>


-----

/* --- Connection Variables ---*/

$connnection_server = "[server]";

$connection_database = "[db]";

$connection_user =  "[username]";

$connection_password = "[password]";
```

I know this might sound like a dumb question (obviously, I'm a newbie), but what is the document root? What does "outside the document root" and "out of the Apache Web server" mean?

For now, as I'm learning, I'mv just on MAMP, but when I do go on a commercial server, say Godaddy's, what what would that mean?

Also, I'm assuming

```
$connnection_server = "[server]";

$connection_database = "[db]";

$connection_user =  "[username]";

$connection_password = "[password]";
```

in the example above means that these variable are on a separate file (e.g., connection_var.php), correct?

Thanks in advance for your knowledge and help.

Jen

Comment: This means that you should put the file outside of the www or public_html folder in your webserver. I am not shure does godaddy lets you do that.For the variables you can define them as constants and include file and use them in your code since they will not change at least no so often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document root is the highest directory (top level) that a browser can directly request files or pages from. Take for example:

```
http://example.com/index.php
```

`index.php` is in the document root. There is no higher level that the browser can request.

```
http://example.com/images/mrcode.jpg
```

`mrcode.jpg` is not in the document root because it resides in the `images` directory.

> What does "outside the document root" and "out of the Apache Web server" mean?

Outside of the document root refers to files that are stored above this directory and therefore cannot be directly requested by a browser. For example your directory structure may look like:

```
/websites/example.com/public_html/index.php
```

If you were to store your database credentials in:

```
/websites/example.com/dbdetails.php
```

This would be out of (or above) the document root. Storing connection credentials inside the document root is not considered a vulnerability, however storing them outside can be slightly better. PHP can still access files above the document root (assuming you have permission). Shared hosts typically give you access to one level above the document root.

Your immediate problem is that you're using the deprecated `mysql_*` library. The problem with this is it is being removed from newer versions of PHP and so if you continue to use it, your applications will eventually become completely unusable. The [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) libraries also offer [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) which should be used instead of the escaping methods to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) because they offer greater security. See [here for a good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). If you were told your queries are unsafe then they probably contain [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities.

Comment: Awesome, clear and very informative answer. I'd vote it up if I had the "reputations" required. Thanks, MrCode.